# How to configure Finder to let me rename dotfiles?

Tags: finder, macos

I always have hidden files set to 'visible' in Finder, because I'm a developer and I work with a lot of dotfiles.

But even with this setting, Finder won't let me rename a file beginning with a dot. It also won't let me modify these files by pasting over them etc; it gives an error like "The item “.gitignore” can’t be replaced because it’s invisible." Well, it's not invisible, I can see it, and I want to replace it, and it's mine.

**I know how to use `mv`**. I am asking about doing this with Finder.

Comment: What step specifically do you perform to make invisible files exposed by Finder? What version of Finder / OS X are you running? The error I receive is "**You can’t use a name that begins with a dot “.”, because these names are reserved for the system. Please choose another name.**"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On macOS 10.15 Catalina through 12 Monterey, you now get a warning when you create or rename an "invisible" folder or file, but you are not longer blocked from renaming them.

[image]

On El Capitan (beta build 15A263e), I can not rename dot files and get this message:

[image: You can’t use a name that begins with a dot “.”, because these names are reserved for the system. Please choose another name.]

I use the third party tool [Transmit](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/transmit/id403388562?mt=12) to make changes to invisible files and folders. I wish I knew a way to modify Finder to do what you ask, but someone trickier than I will need to step up with instructions if they are known.

Some time between 10.8 and 10.11 this was prohibited and some time between then and 12 it's allowed again.

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this by doing one of the following to show hidden files (from
https://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/):

- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> in Finder to toggle showing hidden files
- Run `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` and restart Finder

Once you have done this, the system will only warn you when creating dot files.

Comment: thank you so much! This just made my day..

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what version of OS X you're using however I have no problem renaming *dotfiles* in Finder under OS X 10.8.5. That said, If your using a version of OS X that will not allow you to rename *dotfiles* in Finder and you do not want to use Terminal and the `mv` command, then a GUI option you can consider using is [muCommander](http://www.mucommander.com).

Answer (score -3):

You could make an Automator service with a hotkey that pops up and asks for a new name

EDIT:

[I did the work for you](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8fcgpfqxtoqw9j/mv%20hidden%20file.workflow.zip?dl=0).

Add it to ~/Library/Services and define a hotkey in System Preferences.

Comment: Could you expand on this? Perhaps show an example of how you would build such an Automator service?